# Can't filter on json_agg with LIMIT AND OFFSET

Tags: postgresql-9.5

**data** is **jsonb** column type

json:

```
{
    "cart_id": "84e646d6a22a",
    "contacts": {
        "customer": {
            "email": "dd@aaaaa.com",
            "name": "Name",
            "phone": "1234567"
        },
        "receiver": {
            "is_customer": true,
            "name": "AAAA,
            "phone": "99999"
        }
    }
  }
```

Query:

```
SELECT id FROM shop_order 
WHERE data->'contacts'->'customer'->>'phone' like '%12345%' limit 3 offset 3
```

Nice. It's success return filter result. Return 3 records. Nice.

But I need result as json.

I try this:

```
 select json_agg (json_build_object('data', t.data)) from shop_order as t 
WHERE  t.data->'contacts'->'customer'->>'phone' LIKE '%12345%' LIMIT  3 offset 3
```

I need return result with limit and offset 3

But return empty result.

Why?

P.S.
This query:

```
select json_agg (json_build_object('data', t.data))  from shop_order as t
```

return all records from db. But I need only 3 json objects in ARRAY.

Comment: What exactly is the result you want?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  I need return result as json array with 3 json objects. Because LIMIT = 3 and OFFSET = 3

Comment: But how should those json objects look like? Please **[edit]** your question and add a sample result.

Comment: But regardless of this, you should really plan an upgrade to Postgres 12 or 13 if you are using JSON so much. A **lot** has improved in the last 5 years

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I was update my post

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I found solution. This work: SELECT json_agg(shop_order)
FROM (
      select json_build_object('order', t.data) from shop_order as t 
  WHERE  t.data->'contacts'->'customer'->>'phone' LIKE '%123456%' LIMIT 3 OFFSET 3
     ) shop_order